# why isn't my id showing up in django admin list?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a class Task(models.Model), and i didn't define id field explicitly (since it defines automatically for you). I checked in the database, it exists for the Task. Now i would like to display it in the list via list_display property in admin.ModelAdmin. I have a bunch of things in there, only id is not showing up for any of the rows i have. Everything else works fine. Anyone know anything special i have to do to get id to display?

EDIT:
if i define a function as follows:

```
def ID(self, obj):
        return obj.id
```

and i put this function in list_display, it will display id just fine for some reason.

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't show by default. You need to create a custom Admin class for that model and then add 'id' to the list_display value. E.g. in whatever/admin.py:

```
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', etc. etc] 

admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
```

See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) for more details.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks a lot for your response! However, i did put it in the list_display, and it doesn't show up. However, if i put 'ID' per the function definition, it does show up. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Hmmm ... I would need to see the code for the models.Model class and the admin.ModelAdmin class to give you anymore help. Remember, case *is* significant here, so that might be a contributing factor.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have also used list_editable in your admin.ModelAdmin. This causes the ID to be hidden and is a known bug: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12475.

The work around is to state list_display_links option:

```
class AdAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'ad_title', 'status', 'sponsor' ... ]
    list_display_links = ['id', 'ad_title'] # forcing to display id of model
    list_editable = ['status']
    ...
```

Thanks and hope this helps.